# Image Processing - Determine if someone looking into camera

Tags: image-processing, augmented-reality

with image processing libraries like opencv you can determine if there are faces recognized in an image or even check if those faces have a smile on it.

Would it be possible to somehow determine, if the person is looking directly into the camera? As it is hard even for the human eye to determine is someone is looking into the camera or to a close point, i think that this will be very tricky.

Can someone agree?

thanks

Comment: In WWDC 2013, Session 509, the mention that face detection can pick if someones eyes are open or not. So that should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using an eye detection program, I remember doing back a few years ago, and it wasn't that strong, so when we tilt our head slightly off the camera, or close our eyes, the eyes can't be detected.

Is it is not clear, what I really meant was our face must be facing straight at the camera with our eyes open before it can detect our eyes. You can try doing something similar with a bit of tweaks here and there.

Off the top of my head, split the image to different sections, for each ROI, there are different eye classifiers, for example, upper half of the image, u can train the a specific classifiers of how eyes look like when they look downwards, lower half of image, train classifiers of how eyes look like when they look upwards. and for the whole image, apply the normal eye detection in case the user move their head along while looking at the camera.

But of course, this will be based on extremely strong classifiers and ultra clear quality images, video due to when the eye is looking at. Making detection time, extremely slow even if my method is successful.

There maybe other ideas available too that u can explore. It's slightly tricky, but it not totally impossible. If openCV can't satisfy, openGL? so many libraries, etc available. I wish you best of luck!

Comment: The Problem is, that this should be done in an image, where persons are not directly the interesting part of the image. (Far away, where the head fits into 256 x 256 pixel) As this would be very difficult to track, the real application would suffer.

Comment: Check out my face/hand/eye detection program I did back then. This is the result for the eye part on a static image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/64e58.png. The heads all actually is within the size/frame of 256 x 256 pixels. Actually, maybe even smaller. as you can see, in this image, I used a sunset background, pasted some other images, so that the human faces are not directly the interesting part of the image. But the eye detection is still successful with a detection rate of 185.96ms. Hope this helps.

Comment: How did it go on your progress on this? Any headway made?